# Stop styles in `innerHTML` from impacting parent

Tags: html, css, angular, innerhtml

I have created an HTML email that displays correctly in a few email clients I've tested, but when I provide a preview of it on my page, the embedded styles in the `innerHTML` impact the parent.  It must be possible to avoid this because when I view the email in gmail it displays correctly without changing the style of gmail itself.

Here's some HTML that shows the problem (but displays with no side effects in gmail):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            * { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test </pre>
    </body>    
</html>
```

I'm using Angular 4 so I'm including it in my page this way:

```
<div [innerHTML]="myHtml | safeHtml">
</div>
```

...and safeHtml is just a pipe to bypass the Angular checks on the HTML I'm injecting:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(html) {

    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);

  }
}
```

It works, in that it does show the html in the div, but the style info changes everything on the page.  I get it - I'm literally using `*` in my embedded style.  ...but as I say, gmail manages to 'contain' this somehow so it doesn't restyle the parent elements.  How do I accomplish this?

Ideally I'd like total style isolation - like I don't want the parent styles to be impacted by the child or the child styles to be impacted by the parent (which, it seems, is how gmail is behaving).

**Update**

Changing the HTML to the following had it working for email, and contained the CSS, but didn't work embedded in Angular:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html class="my-class">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .my-class * { 
                font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
                color: blue;
            }
            .my-class pre {
                white-space:pre-wrap;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test </pre>
    </body>    
</html>
```

This is because (it seems) the `html` and `body` tags are stripped out when you embed this in a `div` (which makes some sense).  So, just add a parent containing `div` with the class and it all works - both embedded and in the email:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .my-class * { 
                font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
                color: blue;
            }
            .my-class pre {
                white-space:pre-wrap;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="my-class">
            <pre>Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test </pre>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Angular 4 is designed to handle CSS on a per-component basis which should keep it from interfering with the parent components. Maybe you can use an Angular component instead of [innerHTML] to prevent the problem. Here is a reference page: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: But it is already impacting totally unrelated components - it impacts the entire page, regardless of what component contains the html.  Like the fonts on my menu change, which isn't even a parent component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach as @petryuno1 advised is to use a component as it would scope the CSS/styles to only that component, but at a basic level can you apply a class to the `<div [innerHTML]="myHtml | safeHtml"></div>` such as:

`<div class="foo" [innerHTML]="myHtml | safeHtml"></div>`

Then modify the css to target `*` of the class instead if a component is not possible?

`.foo * { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }`

The `class` property on that `<div>` would remain regardless of modifications to `innerHTML`.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: As I mention above, the embedded styles are already impacting styles in unrelated components.  I think it is because I'm specifically bypassing the security trust so the css is just given the browser unaltered, and the browser is dutifully just applying them as it should.

Comment: The solution you propose helps me to embed the HTML, but the problem is I'm generating an entire HTML document to use as an email - I guess I can try this and apply this class to every element in the embedded HTML?  That might work - let me check it out...

Comment: `*` will apply to **everything** on the page and parent page. The presence of `*` though makes it seem like you're goal is to apply the `font-family` to **ALL** elements within `[innerHTML]`. Prefixing/name-spacing with a class would help prevent parent elements from being affected by `*`. A component with a `styles` or `stylesUrl` would do it's own namespacing by default, preventing parent elements from being affected.

Comment: Right - but this HTML is generated server side and used as an HTML email which I am just trying to give the user a preview of.  I get what you are saying, but I don't see how it can solve this problem - it isn't really practical to generate an angular component server side (I can see how this might be possible, but if it comes to that I'll just render it as a PDF).  Google is somehow displaying my HTML in the email within a web browser without it mangling their page, so it must be possible.  Prefixing with a unique class in the embedded HTML seems like it would work though - I'll try it out.

Comment: One other note - you say the presence of `*` makes it seem like my goal is to apply `font-family` to ALL elements within `[innerHTML]` - yes that is my goal.  Just not to have it impact items outside of `[innerHTML]` - anyway, the prefix ideas is good, a POC is working for me.  Let me finish converting the real deal and I'll accept this answer if it works out (seems like it will).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution I found using Angular for a similar problem (having to show the HTML of an e-mail in a page) is to create a new Component to display the preview and setting the encapsulation to ShadowDom.

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-email-view',
  templateUrl: './email-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./email-view.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class EmailViewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  preview: any;
```

After that, I simply insert the `preview` variable in the `[innerHtml]` element.

The ShadowDom is responsible for encapsulating the Style and not letting it affect the other components. For more information you can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM).